# how do I prevent empty data inserting into mysql database from post http request

Tags: php, post, get

I made the post function from the application in c#, then I want to insert the post data into the mysql database via the php file.

how can I prevent the entry of empty data into the database? because if I open the URL http://example.com/api/index.php directly in the browser, then there will be empty data that goes into the database, except the ip address.

I do not want if someone opens the url http://example.com/api/index.php directly, then there will be empty data entering the database because it can cause spam.

c# code :

```
    public void uploadFile(string url, string filepath)
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        try
        {
            webClient.UploadFile(url, "POST", filepath);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            webClient.Dispose();
        }
    }

string lickey = desktoppath + randnumber + ".lic";
uploadFile(string.Format(url + api, 
                new object[] 
                { 
                    licKeyID,
                    name,
                    GetAddress(),
                }), 
                lickey);

private string url = "http://example.com/api";
private string api = "/index.php?lickey_id={0}&username={1}&password={2}&address={3}";
```

php code :

```
<?php
include('config.php');

$uploaddir = 'newdir/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['license_id']) . '.lic';

$blacklist = array(".php", ".phtml", ".php3", ".php4", ".html", ".htm");
foreach ($blacklist as $item)
if(preg_match("/$item\$/i", $_FILES['file']['name'])) exit;

$f1 = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$fd = fopen($uploaddir.$id, 'w') or die("failed to create file");
fwrite($fd, $f1);
fclose($fd);

$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `License` WHERE 
`license_id`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['license_id'])."' AND `checked`='false'");
if(mysql_num_rows($check) > 0)
{
exit(0);
}

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `License` SET 
`ip`='".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',      
`file`='$uploaddir".$id."',
`license_id`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['license_id'])."',
`username`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username'])."',
`address`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['address'])."',
`checked`='false'");
echo mysql_error();
mysql_close($dbcon);
?>
```

Comment: check if `license_id'`, `username`, .. are set or not. And/or work with an authtoken sent by the app.

Comment: Your code is unsecure! Use prepared statements! And I'd rather have a whitelist for filetypes than a blacklist.

Comment: And to save the uploaded file you wouldn't need to read and write it, just use [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: okay, i know, this is just the basis that I made on localhost

Comment: I'll try changing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validate input.

This can be done in many ways. One of them could be checking if `$_FILES` global variable contains `file` key, and if `$_GET` contains `license_id`, `username` and `address`.

```
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    die('Request invalid');
}
```

PS. Generally, using global variables is burdened with a security risk. What you could do, without refactoring this completely, think about adding a custom header (like `X-Client: My Fancy CSharp Application`), and validating it inside PHP code.